# Odoo - Add button next to the 'Create' one

Tags: odoo

[SOLVED]

```
<t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
            Create Customer Site
        </button>
    </t>
</t>
```

They changed name of the button class in 'o_list_button_add' in v10 of Odoo.
Found it in web.base

Thanks.

---

I would like to add a button next to the 'Create' one.

I tried with the xpath tag, like this:

```
<template>
    <xpath expr="//div[@class='.o_list_buttons']" position="after">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="customer_button"
                string="Create Customer" type="action"/>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

but it did not work.

Does anybody know how to do it?

[EDIT]

I am using Odoo v10.

Here's the __manifest__.py

```
{
'name': "Broadband",

'summary': """
        Manage Network Sites
    """,

'description': """
""",

'author': "Author",
'website': "",

# Categories can be used to filter modules in modules listing
# Check https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/master/openerp/addons/base/module/module_data.xml
# for the full list
'category': 'Draft',
'version': '0.1',

# any module necessary for this one to work correctly
'depends': ['base', 'product', 'base_multi_image', 'board', 'backend_theme_v10'],

# always loaded
'data': [
    'security/security.xml',
    'security/ir.model.access.csv',
    'views/views.xml',
    'views/product_view.xml',
    'views/wkf.xml',
    'views/component_view.xml',
    'views/competitor_view.xml',
    'views/voucher_view.xml',
    'views/partner_view.xml',
    'views/provider_view.xml',
    'views/site_board.xml',
    'views/customer.xml',
    'views/interventions.xml',
    'views/states_count.xml',
    'views/notification.xml',
],
# only loaded in demonstration mode
'demo': [
    'demo/demo.xml',
],
'qweb': ['views/templates.xml', 'views/views.xml'],
'installable': True,
'application': True,
```

}

I'm using your code inside the templates.xml.
Do I have to tell to Odoo where to use it, maybe?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<templates xml:space="preserve">

<t t-extend="ListView.buttons" t-name="add_create_button">
    <t t-jquery="button.o_list_button_add" t-operation="after">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            Create Customer Site
        </button>
    </t>
</t>

</templates>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add it after `create` button use:

For `ListView`:

```
<template xml:space="preserve">
    <t t-extend="ListView.buttons">
        <t t-jquery="button.oe_list_add" t-operation="after">
            <!-- Your button here -->
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

For `FormView`:

```
<t t-extend="FormView.buttons">
    <t t-jquery="button.oe_form_button_create" t-operation="after">
        <button type="button">My button</button>
     </t>
 </t>
```

Add dependancy to `base` module in `__openerp__.py`:

```
{
    ...

    'depends': ['base'],

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work.
I tried to put it either in the view or in the templates file, but it does not add anything.

Comment: @MicheleZaccheddu Did you add it as qweb template ?

Comment: I have that too. 
I also tried, for the ListView, to change the t-jquery to 'button.o_list_button_add' like the base_import module do, but nothing yet.

Comment: @MicheleZaccheddu I tested this code in both `odoo 8` and `openerp 7` and the buttons appears next to create button.Please add `__openerp__.py` and the template file, I am curious to know the problem.

Comment: I've added them

Comment: @MicheleZaccheddu Change `o_list_button_add` to `oe_list_add`.

Comment: Same story. Nothing happen. Could they have changed it in the v10?